# right to left arabic characters in tables

Tags: tables, babel, arabic

How to get right to left arabic characters inside a tabular environment with the arabi package  without to have to insert the `\AR` command in each cell ?

```
\documentclass[A4,12pt]{article}
  \usepackage[ utf8 ]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[arabic]{babel} 

  \begin{document}

       الإسم 

      اللقب

     تاريخ الإزدياد   


  \vspace{2cm}

  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c|}}

   الإسم&
  \AR{اللقب}&
   تاريخ الإزدياد  

 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of `array`  to create a new column type, first you need to define a `Box` which save the contents of the cell

```
\newsavebox{\RTLbox}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\RTLbox}}c<{\end{lrbox}\AR{\unhbox\RTLbox}}}
```

---

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ utf8 ]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel} 
\usepackage{array}

\newsavebox{\RTLbox}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\RTLbox}}c<{\end{lrbox}\AR{\unhbox\RTLbox}}}

\begin{document}

       الإسم

      اللقب

     تاريخ الإزدياد


\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{R|}}

   الإسم&
  اللقب &
تاريخ الإزدياد  

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]